# Why is this gradient descent algorithm only working for unacceptable $\alpha$ and iteration number?

Tags: python, algorithm, regression, gradient-descent

**This has been solved. Solution:**  I was accidentally using the cost function instead of the derivative of the cost function when applying gradient descent.

I am trying to implement a simple gradient descent algorithm for linear regression in python, with the linear regression line being y = (θ0) + (θ1)x. My entire code is outlined below. The function costFunction() calculates the derivative of the cost function (the gradient of the cost function). Namely, costFunction0 is the derivative of the cost function with respect to the y-intercept of the regression line, and costFunction1 is the derivative of the cost function with respect to the gradient of the regression line.

```
import numpy as np 
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('data.txt', 'r') as inputfile:
    results = list(csv.reader(inputfile))
population = [] 
profit = []
for i in results:
    population.append(float(i[0]))
    profit.append(float(i[1]))

#Function to calculate the cost function for the y-intercept term.
def costFunction0(xData, yData, theta0, theta1):
    cost0 = 0
    for j in xrange(len(xData)):
        cost0 += (theta0 + theta1*xData[j] - yData[j])
    return cost0

#Function to calculate the cost function for the θ_1 term.
def costFunction1(xData, yData, theta0, theta1):
    cost1 = 0
    for j in xrange(len(xData)):
        cost1 += (theta0 + theta1*xData[j] - yData[j]) * xData[j]
    return cost1

#Gradient descent algorithm.
def gradientDescent(xData, yData, a, iterations, theta0, theta1):
    J = []
    it = []
    for i in xrange(iterations):
        cost0 = costFunction0(xData, yData, theta0, theta1)
        cost1 = costFunction1(xData, yData, theta0, theta1)
        tmp0 = theta0 - a*cost0
        tmp1 = theta1 - a*cost1
        theta0 = tmp0
        theta1 = tmp1
        J.append(cost1)
        it.append(i)

    return theta0, theta1, J, it

result = gradientDescent(population, profit, 0.000000005, 9000, 0.5, 3)

print 'y = %s + %sx' % (result[0], result[1])

plt.plot(result[3], result[2])
plt.show()

x = np.arange(0, 30, 1)
y = result[0] + result[1]*x
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(population, profit, 'rx')
plt.xlim((4, 24))
plt.ylim((-5, 25))
plt.show()
```

In the code I implement the gradient descent. I also plot the cost function value at each iteration, which confirms to me that the algorithm performs somewhat appropriately. (It can be seen to clearly converge.)

**The problem**

This code is fine in that it does actually work and produce what looks like a decent regression line for the data sets that I have tried it on. However, in order to get this result I need to use a ridiculous value of alpha and a very large number of iterations. My teacher gets a good regression line (slightly different to mine) with alphe=0.01 and 1500 iterations. He also initialises both of the parameters to zero. If I try the same arguments as him my algorithm doesn't work (it just diverges and stops).

**Questions**

There must be something inherently wrong with my algorithm. My algorithm is either correct but very poorly implemented; or my algorithm is plain wrong.

Could someone please help to identify the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain exactly what costfunction0 and costfunction1 are trying to compute, and explain the derivation of them?  (My suspicion is that these are meant to be the gradient of the cost function, but you have not computed the gradient correctly - in particular note that costfunction0 is never negative!)

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Sure I've edited to explain.

Comment: costfunction0 looks exactly like the cost, not the derivative of the cost?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz thanks for spotting that - I accidentally included the square! I'll try it without now

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz All good now.